# how to calculate this integration

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I am trying to calculate this integration:
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j\omega x}(-\frac{2e^{3j\omega}}{3\omega^2}+\frac{e^{2j\omega}}{\omega^2}-\frac{1}{3\omega^2})d\omega$$
I'm sure it equals to:
$$g(x)=\frac{x}{3}I(0<x<2)+(2-\frac{2x}{3})I(2\leq x<3)$$

Yes, it's a probability distribution function and I am trying to figure out how to go from its characteristic function back to the distribution function. But I have no clue how to deal with this integration. Can any one help?

Comment: What is $\omega$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $d \omega$ instead of $dx$ in the first integral?

Comment: Looks divergent to me...

Comment: Isn't that a Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1):

Let us define the Fouriertransformation of the function $f$ via
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\omega x}f(\omega)\, d\omega.
$$
Your integral is the Fouriertransform of the function
$$
f(\omega)= \dfrac{1}{6\pi}\dfrac{3e^{2j\omega}-2e^{3j\omega}-1}{\omega^{2}}.
$$
But we can rewrite this as
$$
f(\omega) = \dfrac{1}{6\pi}e^{j\omega}\dfrac{\sin^{2}(\omega/2)}{(\omega/2)^{2}} + \dfrac{1}{3\pi}e^{j2\omega}\dfrac{\sin^{2}(\omega/2)}{(\omega/2)^{2}}.
$$
It is well-known that the Fouriertransform of $\dfrac{\sin^{2}(\omega)}{\omega^{2}}$ is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}(2-|x|)(H(x+2)-H(x-2))$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function. If we consider the effect of the scaling factor $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and that the factors $e^{j\omega}$ and $e^{j2\omega}$ will cause a translation of one respectively two steps to the right on the transform side, then it is obvious that the Fouriertransform of $f(\omega)$ will be what you already know.